Keycloak move from 23.0 to 24.0: Account is not fully set up [invalid_grant]
For a test environment, I'm running image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION} in docker compose and have an init script similar to the following (the container is reinited every time - this is not an upgrade question in that sense):
#!/bin/sh
set -xe

export KEYCLOAK_HOME=/opt/keycloak
PATH="$PATH:$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin"
cd "$KEYCLOAK_HOME"/bin

REALM=testing
DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin_password
HOST=keycloak
PORT=8080

./kcadm.sh config credentials \
  --server http://$HOST:$PORT \
  --realm master \
  --user admin \
  --password admin

./kcadm.sh create realms -s "realm=$REALM" -s "enabled=true"

ADMIN_UID=$(./kcadm.sh create users -r $REALM -s "username=admin" -i)
./kcadm.sh add-roles -r $REALM --uusername admin --cclientid realm-management --rolename realm-admin
./kcadm.sh update users/"$ADMIN_UID" -r $REALM -s "enabled=true"
./kcadm.sh update users/"$ADMIN_UID"/reset-password -r $REALM -s type=password -s value=$DEFAULT_PASSWORD -n

############################################
# Reconfigure to use the created realm admin
############################################

./kcadm.sh config credentials \
  --server http://$HOST:$PORT \
  --realm $REALM \
  --user admin \
  --password $DEFAULT_PASSWORD

# setup roles
# setup users
# setup clients

With KEYCLOAK_VERSION=23.0 this is working as expected, but for KEYCLOAK_VERSION=24.0 I get:
...
keycloak-setup-1  | + ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://keycloak:8080 --realm testing --user admin --password admin_password
keycloak-setup-1  | Logging into http://keycloak:8080 as user admin of realm testing
keycloak-1        | 2024-05-24 11:48:34,509 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-1) type="LOGIN_ERROR", realmId="29bee3da-666d-4db5-a16e-558db391412b", clientId="admin-cli", userId="null", ipAddress="10.89.0.173", error="resolve_required_actions", auth_method="openid-connect", grant_type="password", client_auth_method="client-secret", username="admin"
keycloak-setup-1  | Account is not fully set up [invalid_grant]
keycloak-setup-1 exited with code 1
service "keycloak-setup" didn't complete successfully: exit 1

Can someone point me to the actions that are required for keycloak 24, to be able to create and use a user using kcadm.sh? I checked the Release notes for breaking changes, pointing to User Profiles in the upgrade guide. However, I have not been able to locate information relevant for my issue.
When logging in to keycloak, the new user does not have any required actions:

Anyway, I also tried adding  -s 'emailVerified=true' -s 'requiredActions=[]' to the first update users command above, without any change in the outcome. In case it has to do with the new user profile requirements, I also tried  -s 'profileVerified=true', but that is not even an accepted attribute :-(

For me it worked by filling email, first name and last name

Thanks for the hint, indeed it seems version 24 now enforces email, firstName and lastName if the user should actually be used. It is not enforced during user creation. For completeness of the answer, here is the command that made it work:
kcadm.sh create users -r $REALM -s "username=admin" -s "email=admin@mail.com" -s "lastName=admin" -s "firstName=admin" -s "enabled=true" -i.
As of Keycloak 24.0.4 is not necessary to set emailVerified=true.

These fields(email, first name and last name) are not mandatory but without these we can not generate token. when you hit rest api specified user must be specified in the keycloak.

OK, I understand possibly there are other reasons to configure a user than authenticating with that user ... otherwise "not mandatory - except if you want a token" is a bit hard to explain.


In Keycloak by default all attributes settings under User Profile are required on. If so, you need to put all the input fields to make a User. If you turn off the settings for a particular attribute, you can omit in the input field.



In the above image we can see Required filed is on. So we must put lastName during creating of User.



Also for your response: it would help if you included information since when this behavior can be observed. Or at least, which version you are referring to. Because, this answer definitely does not apply to the versions of the original question.

I answered this scenario for KEYCLOAK, 25.0.6. Thanks @Bdot42

This is a nice answer showing how it is connected. I just wish keycloak would mark the "required for login" fields somehow. Or show a warning like "This user cannot login because ...". Or rework the different concepts of "required for creating" vs. "required for login".

I think this occurs because the email, first name and last name attributes are now required fields by default. To disable this, you may access Configure > Realm settings > User profile, select each attribute and turn Required field off.

Maybe, instead of "now", could you mention since which keycloak version they are required? 24.0.4 still allowed creating the users without. Or, are you referring to the strange "not required for creating the user - only if you want to use it" thingy?

By "now", I meant version 25.0.4. In this version, users can be created without these attributes, but they can't log in.

I've only disabled the option "verify profile" action:  Realm Settings-> Authentication -> tab : Required action_>disabled the  "verify profile" action. I'm using the docker image: keycloak/keycloak:26.0. After this, the error "Account is not fully set up " during my postman calls disappeared

im using the version 25.0.2 and i got this problem and i solved by passing the client_id,username,password,grant_type,userId

For me it seems to be an issue with the clientscope "profile". Before Keycloak 24.0.x it seems having it on by default did not cause any issues. But now if it is activated and Firstname and Lastname of a user are not set, this leads to this issue. So depending if you need the scope, you could deactivate it for the public client you use.
